# Draw outside a window's bounds on windows API

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

**How, on Windows API, is it possible to draw outside the bounds of a window (not just outside the client area)?**

I need to be able to draw a drop shadow, a color glow or any other custom design outside the bounds of a window, so I can implement a complete custom window theme design with outer glows or drop shadows. My question is about how to be able to achieve that on the Windows API.

On my searches, I found that some developers use to combine a "ghost" window behind the actual window, so it is possible to draw a shadow or anything on it, while for the user it seems that there is only one single window. Is it a good way of doing what I need?

Well, to accomplish that, I would like to know what functions on the Windows API I need to use to make that "ghost" window to not appear as a separate window when I click on *Alt+Tab* or *Windows+Tab*, and basically to make that "ghost" window really a ghost.

I will be doing that on WPF using C#, but the question is really more related to the Windows API, independently of the framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot render outside a window (well, you *can*, but that is foreign territory, and whoever owns it can undo your actions). The simple solution: Create a window that is larger than what is perceived as your window to accommodate for the window decorations. Not quite as simple as it sounds, because now you have to handle the separation between client area, non-client area, and everything else. This topic is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Visual Studio implements the glow / drop shadow effect by placing 4 small [layered windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) around the actual window, which can be observed by using Spy++ (window class "VisualStudioGlowWindow"). These layered windows are moved and resized whenever the actual window is moved or resized. This will propably be more efficient than having only a single "ghost" window behind the actual window, because you don't have to allocate and process a large, mostly unused backbuffer for the pixels of the layered window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a headless window (without the _ [] X), make it transparent, and inside create a fixed frame (a frame is a rectangle that can contain other things). So 1 window 1 frame and around that frame you can add more frames tha contain semi transparent stuff to create shadow effect.

The main headless window has to be big enough to draw all that inside. If you only create 1 window (all other things be frames or other widgets) there will be no problem with Alt Tab.

Inside the fixed frame you can create again the (_ [] X) buttons  to give the illusion. The API exist for this  and can then be bound to these buttons.

PS: There might me more than one solution